# ObjectListview is not changing the subitem checkbox state

Tags: c#, checkbox, objectlistview

I'm using ObjectListview.

I have enable the usesubitemcheckbox.
but the problem is, when i click the checkboxes in the subitems, the checkboxes is not changing the state.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess would be that there is just no bool aspect assigned.

Check that

- you assigned an `AspectName` for the respective columns
- the aspect is of type `bool`
- the column property `IsEditable` is set to true

If you use `AspectGetter` and `AspectSetter` make sure those use bool as well. I believe subitem checkboxes can also be tri-state using `CheckState` type and setting the column property `TriStateCheckBoxes` to true. (Also use the ObjectListView properties for the checkbox of the first column, its "special" with respect to the other columns).

Comment: Thanks bro :), my another problem is how to trigger the event when the user click the checkbox subitem?

Comment: Please ask a new question for that one. But consider consulting the [OLV manual](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) first. Its pretty comprehensive and covers most daily use scenarios.